# How to get the PC object's table name with Datanucleus v3.2?

Tags: metadata, jdo, datanucleus

**EDIT-This is the answer**
The code I mistakenly used was for editing metadata. For reading it, use the following:

```
pmf.getMetadata(Machineclass.getName()).getTable()
```

---

I've been doing this for a long time using previous datanucleus versions but I'm not sure why isn't it working anymore with v3.2

This code doesn't work because the `getMetaDataForClass` method now always returns `null` !

```
NucleusJDOHelper.getMetaDataForClass(pmf, clazz).getTable()
```

Where **pmf** is the `PersistenceManagerFactory` and **clazz** is a `Class<?>` object representing the class type of the PC (i.e. persistence capable) object which I need to retrieve the table name for.

I'm only using annotations to define my mappings.

To create my `PersistenceManagerFactory`, I'm using the following code:

```
JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

Where **filePath** is a path to a `properties` file with enough data that has been used for a long time without any change.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to **Neil**'s answer, I switched to using the following code sequence:

```
JDOMetadata md = pmf.newMetadata();
PackageMetadata pmd = md.newPackageMetadata(clazz.getPackage());
ClassMetadata cmd = pmd.newClassMetadata(clazz);
return cmd.getTable();
```

I made sure that the class I'm inspecting is having the proper metadata

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "machine_table", detachable = "true", cacheable = "true")
public class Machine {
```

Now `cmd.getTable()` returns `null` too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use some internal (unsupported?) API when JDO has had a Metadata API since JDO v2.x IIRC? This one here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/metadata_api.html

Comment: `cmd.getTable()` returns null :(

Comment: so you haven't specified the table name for that class, as per the javadocs of that method

Comment: First it didn't have, the relative annotation was commented. But now it's uncommented. I cleaned the project, inspected the generated classes and made sure that the .class file was enhanced and had the proper table name.

But still, it returns null !

Comment: The code I was using was for editing metadata. I'll mention the one for **reading** metadata in my question. It's at the end of the page you referred to. Thank you.